# Laravel validation differences on update and save

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Jeffrey Way's model validation (https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-Model-Validation) to validate both on save and update. With this method, let's say you fill a update some fields on an entry, then call the `save()` method, the validation will run on all the fields currently set on the entry. But if the validation requires a field, say the email address, to be unique, the validation will fail because it already exists:

User.php:

```
protected static $rules = [
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
    'firstname' => 'required',
    'lastname' => 'required'
];
```

Controller.php:

```
     // Get user from id
    $user = User::find($id);

    // Update user
    $user->update($data);

    // Validation when model is saved, via Way\Database\Model
    if ($user->save())
    {
            return Response::json([
                'data' => $user->toArray()
            ], 200);
    }

    if ($user->hasErrors())
    {
        return Response::json([
            'errors' => $user->getErrors()
        ]);
    }
```

Will return errors because the email address failed the validation. So, with this method, how do you tell the validator to ignore the unique rule for the email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I use similar behaviour with different approach. Using this model, I thing you shold override the validate method to get the rules from a custom method, in witch you could set your new rules for existing models.

Something like this could work:

```
protected function processRules($rules = array()) {
     $result = [];
     if (empty($rules)) {
         $rules = static::$rules; 
     }
     // Add unique except :id
     $replace = ($this->exists()) ? ',' . $this->getKey() : '';
     foreach ($rules as $key => $rule) {
         $result[$key] = str_replace(',:' . $this->getKeyName(), $replace, $rule);
     }

     return $result;       

}
```

And override your validate method to call the `proccessRules` method.

```
 public function validate() {
     $v = $this->validator->make($this->attributes, $this->processRules(static::$rules), static::$messages);
     if ($v->passes()) {
         return true;
     }
     $this->setErrors($v->messages());
     return false;
 }
```

So now, you can define your `email` rule as `required|email|unique:users:id`, and when its a new User the rule should be `required|email|unique:users` and when you update the User with id 1234 the rule will be `required|email|unique:users:1234`.

I hope it works fine for you.

Comment: This is perfect - works fine. There is a ")" missing in your code, though, after `(empty($rules)`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. It's almost the same kind of Model that I'm currently using - with some other adds -, so I've already fixed that problem. Maybe you could be interested in Ardent (https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent), I'm using this one. I fixed the parenthesis ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem! I decided the problem on their own.

```
protected static $rules = [
    'email' => $user->email == Input::get('email') ? 'required|email' : 'required|email|unique:users',
    'firstname' => 'required',
    'lastname' => 'required'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it using this package, because you need to pass id for the `unique` rule. You could do it this way:

```
protected static $rules = [
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,{id}',
    'firstname' => 'required',
    'lastname' => 'required'
];
```

and extend this model to add your custom validation method to replace `{id}` with `id` attribute